# How to Find Download/Upload Speeds of Devices on Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, wrt54g

I have a Linksys WRT54G V8.  I have a problem where our internet is both slow and our ISP gives us very junky modems that will cause slow downs occasionally.  Due to both of these problems, I need the ability to see live the download and upload speeds of the devices connected to my network so that I can find bandwidth hogs and know if a slow down is caused by a device or by the modem.  I installed DD WRT thinking it could do this, but it does not by default.  Can anyone help?

EDIT: My previous question, as far as I can tell, was not specific enough.  I asked how to monitor traffic.  I fear that some will interpret this as me just wanting to see how many connections a device has made or how much it has downloaded total.  What I really am in need of is just seeing the CURRENT download and upload speeds of each device.  I will try to delete my previous question.

A screenshot of my DD WRT (micro version):
http://s2.postimg.org/l0x3y55vd/image.png

Note the available memory and lack of a statistics tab.

Comment: Are you trying to test internal speeds (device to device) or for each device to the internet?

Comment: If one of our iPads is downloading (maybe because my sister's Pinterest app is doing a huge update in the background, for example) at 300 kb/s, I want to be able to see that from one of my computers or the router settings.  If my phone is not doing anything and is therefore downloading at 0 kb/s, I want to be able to see that.  I just need to see what devices are actively using the internet and how much they are using so I can go shut it off.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. not sure how your interface looks, but on my Asus wrt router it displays it in a graph showing me "live" of downloads and uploads and be which devices. 
Try Iftop and see if that is what you are looking for.

On your firmware of wrt, do you have a statistics tab?if so, look in there. If you could, post a screenshot of what your firmware looks like.

Comment: I do not seem to have a statistics tab.  See the link to the screenshot I just posted.  David seems to know what I'm looking for though.  If you see here, http://www.howtogeek.com/222740/how-to-the-monitor-the-bandwidth-and-data-usage-of-individual-devices-on-your-network/ , the second image within the post shows another example of exactly what I'm looking for.  I have DD WRT micro, so keep that in mind as well.

Answer (score 0):

I what you are looking for is this:

[Per-user Live Down/Upload Rate Monitoring](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=75275)

[image]

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I'm looking for.  However, because I have the WRT54G, an old router, I have the micro version of DD WRT.  I also have very little memory available.  Do you know if it will still work?